# Fill in missing hours in data

Tags: powerquery

I have a dataset that looks like this:
[image: Dataset. Contains 6 columns, the first one with dates, the second one with hours]

The second column("Hora") contains all the hours in which there was an amount of money spent. The first column contains the date in which that amount of money was spent.

I'd like to add in the rows corresponding all hours in which there was no money spent, with their corresponding dates, if possible, excluding 2 to 7 o'clock.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited version

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Data", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Data"}, {{"stuff", each _ & Table.ExpandListColumn(#table({"Data", "Hora"},{{_[Data]{0},List.Difference({0..1,8..23}, _[Hora])}}), "Hora"), type table}}),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),{"Data"}),
#"Expanded stuff" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "stuff", ColumnsToExpand,  ColumnsToExpand)
in #"Expanded stuff"
```

[image]

You can apply a sort afterwards if needed

Comment: The rows with same date and hour shouldn't be deleted as they contain data about different things that should be kept. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: All hours of all days are being inserted, can hours in which there's already data inserted be removed? Like: if there's an empty row and a row with same hour and date, make the one which is null be removed.

Comment: The request was "I'd like to add in the rows corresponding all hours in which there was no money spent, with their corresponding dates, if possible, excluding 2 to 7 o'clock" That is what I believe I have done. Your additional requirements are confusing and you have not provided a sample input or output for this new requirement. Feel free to start another question, and if doing so, please post sample data as text, not images. No one wants to retype all that.